# How to go particular point location inside UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, position, cgpoint

I have UIWebView and  have x & y coordinates. When i go to viewcontroller i need to go that particular coordinate inside UIWebView. But it loads the view from zero position. It's like a bookmark on page. When i bookmark i'm getting coordinates value and selected text. Later, if selected text coming i need to go that point.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

 wbCont = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 45, 320, 568)];

  [wbCont loadHTMLString:webString baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:wbCont];

[self.view addSu

NSUserDefaults *xv=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    float bx=[xv floatForKey:@"xvalue"];


    NSUserDefaults *yv=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    float by=[yv floatForKey:@"yvalue"];



    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // getting an NSString
    NSString  *savedValue = [prefs stringForKey:@"got"];



    if(savedValue){


             CGPoint pt = CGPointMake(bx, by);


          NSLog(@"CGPoint Value – %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(pt));



        }


    }
```

Comment: Why do you have 3 references to standardUserDefaults?

Comment: I need 3 values. that's why.. why downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
  [webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(100, 100) animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: do it on `-(void) viewWillAppear`

Comment: i've edited my original answer. Try that but make sure you have set the delegate of the webview to your viewcontroller

Comment: I have webview size is 320,568. But after using your code, my webview doesn't appear full screen. It take 100,100. I don't want to 100,100 CGRectSize. I need to go that point. But your code going to that point.